# Simple Laravel route not working

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am currently in the middle of doing a Laravel tutorial on Youtube and I've been catching on pretty quickly but I hit a snag and I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.  I'm trying to route to a view and I am receiving an error saying that the page does not exist.  Here is what I got (forgive me if my terminology is lacking):

The web.php file in the routes folder is configured for 'companies' to go to the 'CompaniesController':

```
Route::resource('companies', 'CompaniesController');
```

The create function located in the CompaniesController only purpose is to return the view 'companies.create' located in the appropriate place, 'resources/views/companies/create.blade.php'

```
 public function create()
{
    //
    return view('companies.create');

}
```

If more information is needed let me know but this should be pretty straight forward.  Other functions in the controller work fine, its only the one that is the most simple that isn't working.

Appreciate any help I get.

Comment: what route are you calling from the browser ? Please share your browser url

Comment: The browser call is http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/create

Comment: Same as what the video tutorial suggests and his works, here is the link: https://youtu.be/Qw_jQKg_cXE

Comment: Yes, that should work. I hope you are not using route prefix

Comment: @DarkPanda182 Do your other routes work?  Is it just the create view you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

If your http request is `GET`:

```
Route::get('/companies', 'CompaniesController@create')
```

Else if request is `POST`:

```
Route::post('/companies', 'CompaniesController@create')
```

Answer (score 0):

`create` would respond to a POST request by default, e.g., the endpoint of a creation form. It sounds like you're trying to display a simple view with a GET. 
See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers